# Who runs the Bitcoin wiki?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

Who runs the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://www.bitcoin.it)? What is their Twitter account?

1. I am looking for the community, group or person who runs this site.
2. Does this being have a Twitter account? The account [@bitcoin_wiki](https://twitter.com/@bitcoin_wiki) exists, but they have only 30 followers, which makes me think they aren’t the real people: so small a follower count doesn’t feel right.

I ask because the site is down and Twitter is a very easy way tell the site administrators. I suppose another method of contact would be fine too.

Comment: I think it is Martti Malmi at https://twitter.com/search?q=martti%20malmi&src=typd @marttimalmi.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: A tweet with a screen print of crash: https://twitter.com/WillyBruns/status/601616473111441408

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's down because it's hosted on the same server as bitcointalk.org (in a separate VM), and the [bitcointalk.org server is down](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/36tqq4/bitcointalk_server_compromised_due_to_social/). Having them both on the same server has been convenient, but it's unnecessarily disruptive for both sites to go down at once when there are troubles with the host machine/OS/network, so the wiki is going to be moved elsewhere in the near future.

I own the domain name and handle some technical aspects of the wiki's operation, but I am not the best person to contact for most technical problems, and I am not responsible for dictating wiki policy. For both of these things, it's best to join #bitcoin-wiki on Freenode or post in the Wiki section of the forum.